# AnyDAC components execute SQL query slower than FIBPlus components

Tags: performance, delphi, firedac, anydac, fibplus

The following SQL command returns approximately 4.500 records and contains integer-, string- and blob (text) values. All indexes are set properly. Furthermore we know that the **in** clause is not the best but that shouldn't bother us right now. The SQL command is executed on a firebird 3.0 server:

```
Select
distinct O.Nr, O.Betreff, O.Text, O.Absenderadresse, O.Gelesen, O.Datum, O.Ordner, O.TextNotiz, M.ID, R.PosNr as RPosNr, R.AddressType, R.Address, R.Name, A.Nr as AttachmentNr, M.Bezeichnung as Mailordner, 0 as Archived

from Table1 O
  left join Table2 R on (R.Nr = O.IDNr)
  join Table3 M on (M.Nr = O.Ordner)
  and (M.PersonalNr=O.PersonalNr)
  left join Table4 A on (A.Nr = O.IDNr)

where (O.PersonalNr = 12)
and O.Ordner in (608,7440,7441,7444,6144,7091,5467,617,2751,710,6580,2812,609,7054,7194,7479,614,620,7030,615,3434,4883,619,6465,7613)
```

We executed the SQL command in an **external application** (from which we know that this application uses the **FIBPlus** components) and in our very basic sample **Delphi7 application** (which uses the original **AnyDAC** database components Version 8.0.5). If we fetch all records into a grid, we have the following performance:

- External Application with FIBPlus   ~ 200 – 400 milliseconds
- Delphi7 with AnyDAC ~ 3.500 – 4.500 milliseconds

In our Delphi7 program we have connected a **TADQuery** to it's own **TADTransaction**. 
The default settings are used for both components, except the ReadOnly property of the TADTransaction, which we changed to True

Now we wonder why the external application is approximately 10 times faster than our Delphi7 program? 
Are there any properties which we can modify to speed up our Delphi 7 program?

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Try `Query.FetchOptions.Items := [fiDetails, fiMeta];`. By default fiBlobs is included also

Comment: If i exclude **fiBlobs** from the `Query.FetchOptions.Items` the query has to reload the blob values during the reading of the data. This approach makes the whole process slower than the current approach (meaning **fiBlobs** is included)...